# Converting multiple columns with timestamp values to GMT time without using DateTimeIndex in pandas

Tags: python, timestamp, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns with timestamps:

```
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame({"start_time": range(1380805471, 1380805481), "end_time" : range(1380805481, 1380805491)})

In [13]: df.ix[:,['start_time','end_time']]
Out[13]: 
   start_time    end_time
0  1380805471  1380805481
1  1380805472  1380805482
2  1380805473  1380805483
3  1380805474  1380805484
4  1380805475  1380805485
5  1380805476  1380805486
6  1380805477  1380805487
7  1380805478  1380805488
8  1380805479  1380805489
9  1380805480  1380805490
```

The second step was just so that the start_time is displayed before end_time or else the columns are displayed alphabetically with only `df`.

Now, I want to convert these timestamps into human readable times for display. Currently, I am doing::

```
In [15]: import datetime as dt

In [16]: df['start_time'] = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in df.start_time]

In [17]: df['end_time'] = [dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(t) for t in df.end_time]

In [18]: df.ix[:,['start_time','end_time']]
Out[18]: 
           start_time            end_time
0 2013-10-03 18:34:31 2013-10-03 18:34:41
1 2013-10-03 18:34:32 2013-10-03 18:34:42
2 2013-10-03 18:34:33 2013-10-03 18:34:43
3 2013-10-03 18:34:34 2013-10-03 18:34:44
4 2013-10-03 18:34:35 2013-10-03 18:34:45
5 2013-10-03 18:34:36 2013-10-03 18:34:46
6 2013-10-03 18:34:37 2013-10-03 18:34:47
7 2013-10-03 18:34:38 2013-10-03 18:34:48
8 2013-10-03 18:34:39 2013-10-03 18:34:49
9 2013-10-03 18:34:40 2013-10-03 18:34:50
```

My question - is there any pandas specific way of doing this which doesn't require using list comprehensions or is this the only way?

The other way, I know of, for dealing with timestamps is using DateTimeIndex and then using localize methods to convert into the desired timezone. But this way requires that you make the column an index and thus, can be done for just one column. Please correct me if my understanding of DateTimeIndex is wrong. Also, I don't require these columns to be indexes.

So is there any better way of doing this using pandas?

**UPDATE**

```
In [52]: df['start_time'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'],unit='s'),tz='UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
     end_time          start_time
0  1380805481 2013-10-03 13:04:31
1  1380805482 2013-10-03 13:04:32
2  1380805483 2013-10-03 13:04:33
3  1380805484 2013-10-03 13:04:34
4  1380805485 2013-10-03 13:04:35
5  1380805486 2013-10-03 13:04:36
6  1380805487 2013-10-03 13:04:37
7  1380805488 2013-10-03 13:04:38
8  1380805489 2013-10-03 13:04:39
9  1380805490 2013-10-03 13:04:40
```

Its still showing GMT time while I want GMT+5.30 even after specifying 'Asia/Kolkata' as the  argument. Am I missing something?

I need to convert both the columns to display the time in local timezone. The result of the DateTimeIndex is only visible if I set it as the index.

```
In [55]: t = pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'],unit='s'),tz='UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')

In [59]: df.set_index(t, inplace=True)

In [60]: df
Out[60]: 
                             end_time          start_time
2013-10-03 18:34:31+05:30  1380805481 2013-10-03 13:04:31
2013-10-03 18:34:32+05:30  1380805482 2013-10-03 13:04:32
2013-10-03 18:34:33+05:30  1380805483 2013-10-03 13:04:33
2013-10-03 18:34:34+05:30  1380805484 2013-10-03 13:04:34
2013-10-03 18:34:35+05:30  1380805485 2013-10-03 13:04:35
2013-10-03 18:34:36+05:30  1380805486 2013-10-03 13:04:36
2013-10-03 18:34:37+05:30  1380805487 2013-10-03 13:04:37
2013-10-03 18:34:38+05:30  1380805488 2013-10-03 13:04:38
2013-10-03 18:34:39+05:30  1380805489 2013-10-03 13:04:39
2013-10-03 18:34:40+05:30  1380805490 2013-10-03 13:04:40
```

How should I do it for both columns?

Comment: You can just use `apply` and assign direct to the column like so `df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))`, this is better than a list comprehension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was introduced in 0.12. MUCH faster as its all done in cython. the unit
is number of epoch seconds (you can also pass for example 'ms' if your datetimes in milliseconds since epoch). [docs here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#converting-to-timestamps)

```
In [6]: df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'],unit='s')

In [7]: df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'],unit='s')

In [8]: df
Out[8]: 
             end_time          start_time
0 2013-10-03 13:04:41 2013-10-03 13:04:41
1 2013-10-03 13:04:42 2013-10-03 13:04:42
2 2013-10-03 13:04:43 2013-10-03 13:04:43
3 2013-10-03 13:04:44 2013-10-03 13:04:44
4 2013-10-03 13:04:45 2013-10-03 13:04:45
5 2013-10-03 13:04:46 2013-10-03 13:04:46
6 2013-10-03 13:04:47 2013-10-03 13:04:47
7 2013-10-03 13:04:48 2013-10-03 13:04:48
8 2013-10-03 13:04:49 2013-10-03 13:04:49
9 2013-10-03 13:04:50 2013-10-03 13:04:50
```

Note that this is in GMT already. `datetime.fromtimestamp` does a conversion to local tz). If you want that.

```
In [21]: DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'],unit='s'),tz='UTC').tz_convert('EST')
Out[21]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-10-03 08:04:41, ..., 2013-10-03 08:04:50]
Length: 10, Freq: None, Timezone: EST
In [32]: DataFrame(dict(end_time = DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'],unit='s'),tz='UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata').asobject))
```

To convert to the tz of Asia/Kolkata. You have to represent this as object. This is will work.

```
                    end_time
 0  2013-10-03 18:34:41+05:30
 1  2013-10-03 18:34:42+05:30
 2  2013-10-03 18:34:43+05:30
 3  2013-10-03 18:34:44+05:30
 4  2013-10-03 18:34:45+05:30
 5  2013-10-03 18:34:46+05:30
 6  2013-10-03 18:34:47+05:30
 7  2013-10-03 18:34:48+05:30
 8  2013-10-03 18:34:49+05:30
 9  2013-10-03 18:34:50+05:30
```

Comment: @Jeff That worked but the converted time is not in the local timezone even after specifying the timezone as the argument. Please see the update above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`

```
df['start_time'] = df['start_time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
df['end_time'] = df['end_time'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(x))
```

This will achieve what you want